# Do you lose money when transferring between wallets?

Tags: blockchain

I just recently 0.0306 BTC from a friend, but the weird thing is that he sent me 0.0316 BTC.

I got 0.0306 BTC, 0.0010 BTC less.

So do you lose money when transferring in the blockchain ?

This is the [blockchain link](https://blockchain.info/tx/d22b9fdaa66ac647fc99bd1d9295da7964397a6f833cce50ae15a3a65a9cd0e6) of my transaction.

Answer (score 2):

Bitcoin transactions always pay fees. Your friend had `0.04488434 BTC`, he sent you `0.0306 BTC`, paid miner fee `0.00036984 BTC` and his change was `0.0139145 BTC`

> So do you lose money when transferring in the blockchain ?

Bitcoin transactions are not free

Comment: Is there a deterministic way to calculate how much miner fees I will have to pay in a given transaction ?

Comment: you can set **any** fee while creating transaction. but all clients today calculate the fee themselves basing on their algorithms. i always pay 1 satoshi/byte for my outgoing transactions with my own transaction creating tool :)

Comment: how can you set the cost/transaction ? why would that be even allowed ? I mean if I am sending you BTC I would obviously like to pay the least amount as transaction fees. Its like going to a shop and you deciding what is the price of the item you want to buy ? What am I missing here ?

Comment: You are using `standard` cleint for creating/sending transaction. I use my own tool.

Comment: @ng.newbie While a client is free to set any fee they like, miners (who ultimately include your transaction in the blocks they mine) are also free to reject it. Each block has space for a limited number of transactions. Transactions with higher fees get priority. Transactions with no fees usually get ignored.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you do lose money.  When you send someone, you'll pay the transaction fee as Bitcoin mining requires a lot of hardware.